# Dynamically "patching" templates

Tags: php, oop, templates

I have a little conception problem.

I created a View class that you use that way :

```
$view = new View('title');
$view->setTemplate('name_of_template');
$view->setVar('name', 'value');
$view->display();
```

The templates are simple PHP/HTML files that are included in the View class when `display` is called.

Then I have "modules". They are objects which can be either activated or deactivated, and they should be allowed to change the behaviour of a page. However I don't want to change a script just because of a module : all the code belonging to it have to be in his class.

I already have some mechanisms. One of them is Events, a system similar to the classic listen/trigger pattern. You can specify parameters to be sent when an event is triggerred, and decide if some of them can be changed by the listening functions.

An event is triggered just before a page is sent to the client. Listeners can then change or add template variables.

However, I'd like modules to be able to add some elements in templates themselves, and I can't come up with a good way to do this. At the moment I have a method called in the templates where modules can add or change elements. Here's the prototype : `patch($name, $replacement)`
Let's say one of them wants to change a word into a link :

> This is a <?=$this->patch('slot1', 'sentence')?> that can be "patched" by a module. <?=$this->patch('slot2', '')?> They can add elements between paragraphs.

The `patch` calls can be "grabbed" by the module which can then change the word "sentence" into `<a href="page.php">sentence</a>`, or add something in "slot2". If there isn't any module grabbing the call, the $replacement is displayed.

However I must add such calls in the templates every time a module needs to modify something. I'd prefer to leave the templates unchanged and program the "patch" in the module's class.

How would you do to allow modules to "patch" templates, knowing certain modules can be disabled and they shouldn't overwrite each other's changes ?

Edit : some more details.

- Most of the time modules' changes will be small additions or word changes.
- If I have to "mark" the templates in some way, I'd like to be able to do it once without having to add marks if a module needs it.
- The "patches" shouldn't rely on line numbers. They can rely on the contents to some extent, but as much as possible not on entire lines.
- I'd prefer a unified way for additions and modifications, but it's ok if I have two different methods.
- I'm already using output buffering (ob_start, etc) to include the chosen template into one global template.
- I'd prefer using str_replace over preg_replace which is slower, if I choose a system relying on these functions.

Comment: So, what exactly is the question now?

Comment: Sorry, I currently have the worst Internet connection you could ever think of. I noticed a part was missing (because of a reloading and copy-paste problem) and tried to edit for the last 15 minutes...

Comment: Look at how other template engines such as Smarty or Dwoo do it, this should give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. They use a concept of "blocks". It's a good idea but it looks like my "patch" function, and it's not that suitable for little adds or changes. Typically a module will just change a couple of words, or add a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet in a case like that is to use a slimmer markup system. Something like:

This is a {link href="http://www.someurl.com/"}sentence{/link} that can be patched...

Capture the output of your templater using ob_start and ob_get_clean and then run your modules on that output by using a preg_match_all to get all instances of your shortened tags and parse them out. You can then loop through all the matches and replace each one with the rendered output from your modules.

In the example above, the parser would make a call to the "link" module and pass it a single parameter: an array in this format: array( 'href' => 'http://www.someurl.com/' )

That's your best bet to allow modules to overwrite template output without making numerous calls to preg functions. This would require a single preg function call to get all the tags. From there you can use string functions to replace data.

I would actually side with the comments above though and urge you to use a template engine like Smarty unless you have specific reasons for avoiding it. I use Smarty for many of my projects because it can be easily extended and provides excellent separation of PHP/Markup because of that.

Comment: The problem here is that I have to modify the template each time a module needs to patch it.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding your request, or you're not following my workflow: Template compiles and executes all PHP tags in it => Output sent to the module parser where it detects all the {...} tags => Each tag is sent to an instance of the appropriate module, where the module can execute and return the result that should replace that {...} tag. The module would never actually modify the template file directly, but rather replace content in the rendered template output on the fly. So you would never need to edit the template file unless you wanted to change the module name/config.

Comment: If I create a new module, I'd have to change the templates to add the required {...} tags. I'd like to separate the modules' code from the base code, that is the templates shouldn't have references to modules in them

Comment: If you don't want to "tag" up your templates to provide the modules with locations where they can inject their code, then how do you intend to determine where each module inserts/replaces it's content into your template? I mean you're kind of chasing yourself in circles up a tree with this issue. You don't want to tag your templates, you don't want to modify your modules all the time, you're already capturing the output via the output buffer and you don't want to use preg_replace on that output. So basically... you can't do what you want to do no matter who gives you an answer. So why ask?

Comment: You can a) capture the output and load and run all (or specific) modules for that template. they would use preg_match_all or preg_replace to capture and do their work. b) tag your template files and parse those tags to load/execute modules on the code. c) modify your template files each time you want to change how the "modules" interact with them. That's it. Those are the only 3 ways you can do what you want, and we've all suggested all 3 of them and you've turned away our answers. So I'm not really sure what you want us to tell you here?

Comment: Tagging is ok if the tags aren't "module dependant". In fact I ended up with a solution recently : I define sections in the templates so it's easier to patch them, then the modules can add text at the beginning or at the end of a section, or use str_replace/preg_replace over one section only. This way there is little room for compatibility issues.